# Java Safepoint: RevokeBias

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, java-8

We are facing an issue with a java applications where lot of safepoints are getting triggered (almost 1/sec). I have enabled GC logging with -"XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime 
-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics –XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1" flag.

and found out that almost every seconds safepoint condition is triggering because of "RevokeBias" . It is happening very frequently and causing issues with the application.

**Can someone tell me what could cause more "RevokeBias" in the application and what should we do to improve this behavior ?**

```
From GC logs: 

    3.039: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0001610 seconds
    24.039: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0001640 seconds

From console logs: 

        7475.858: **RevokeBias**  [     161          0              0    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0   
        vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    
        [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
        @400000005548c3710bf0250c 

        7475.859: **RevokeBias**                       [     161          0              0    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0   
                 vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count

         7475.859: **RevokeBias**                       [     161          0              0    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0
```

Thanks,
Anuj

Comment: Do you know what RevokeBias is and when it happens and you are asking how to avoid it? Or you also don't know what it is?

Comment: I don't know what RevokeBias is. I want to know:  what it is ? and what could probably causing this ? Is there a way to avoid it because it is happening continuously in my application ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Biased locking in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439602/biased-locking-in-java)

Comment: I have marked your question as duplicate then - you should see a link to another question with answers providing information on biased locks in JVM. I also suggest taking a look at [summary in Java docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/6-performance-137236.html#2.1.1) and a [paper with details of biased locking in JVM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/biasedlocking-oopsla2006-wp-149958.pdf)